# Characterization of some property for inverse functions

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

Let's suppose there are two functions $f:A\longrightarrow B$ and
$g:B\longrightarrow B$, such that: $f(x)=f(g(f(x)))$ and $g(x)=g(f(g(x)))$.

I know this should be a trivial question, but what does this mean exactly? Is it possible that this is equivalent to saying that $g$ is an inverse for $f$?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Consider $f : x \mapsto 3$ and $g : x \mapsto 6$, then $f(x) = f(g(f(x)))$ and $g(x) = g(f(g(x)))$, but is $g$ an "inverse" for $f$?

Comment: Your second example has a type error.

Comment: @QthePlatypus What do you mean by type error?

Comment: @Raito No, it's not. So stating those two properties means nothing, doesn't it?

Comment: @any_one I wouldn't say that these two properties mean nothing, at least, they won't be the characterization of inverse functions.

Comment: @Ratio Is it possible that these two properties are a characterization for a sort of Galois connection?

Comment: @any_one You'd need more conditions on these functions to get something interesting, I believe.

Comment: @Ratio mmmh what a pity...thanks anyway!

Comment: @raito in any_one's example they compose g which has a codomain of B with f which has a domain of A.  $f(g(x))$ doesn't work.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Right, I think $g : x \mapsto 3$ would suffice to show that $f \circ g \neq \mathrm{Id_{A}}$.